# Passing null to NumberUtils.createLong function throwing Exception

Tags: java, string, long-integer

I'm trying to convert String to Long by using NumberUtils.createLong function.

As mentioned in the [Doc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#createLong(java.lang.String)), if we pass null value then it will return null. But however I'm getting NumberFormatException for input string "null". Below is the code snippet that I'm using for calling createLong function.

```
NumberUtils.createLong("null") and
NumberUtils.createLong(null)
```

Please help me to fix this Exception.

Thanks.

Comment: `null` and `"null"` are not the same thing. That's why you get an exception.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I even tried with NumberUtils.createLong(null), but that also didn't worked

Comment: @LaveshKarnani Because null is no number. It is nothing, not even zero. Generally, avoid `null` wherever possible (see: `Optional`)! `null` is evil.

Comment: @Amadán, But `createLong` is accepting String, and String can be null as well.

Comment: @LaveshKarnani `createLong(null)` throwing an exception means: the method is _not_ accepting null. Simple and plain. And it is perfectly good style for the method to do so. Obviously the API forces you to make your own decision on what to do with a null value.

Comment: Maybe you have a different library version than what is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says

> Returns `null` if the string is `null`

You're not passing it `null`, you're passing it `"null"`. That's a totally different thing.

```
String s = "null";
System.out.println(s == null);   // false
System.out.println(s.length());  // 4

String t = null;
System.out.println(t == null);   // true
System.out.println(t.length());  // NullPointerException.
```

Comment: I even tried with `NumberUtils.createLong(null)` before, but it was also throwing an numberFormatException.

Comment: @LaveshKarnani please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate that. I suspect you have, for example, not recompiled your code after changing it to use `null`.

Answer (score 0):

you are sending string null by enclosing it in double quotes. Send null instead.

Comment: I already have tried by passing null without quotes, but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberUtils.createLong("null")
```

Fails, because `"null"` does not resemble a number, as `"0"` would do.

```
NumberUtils.createLong(null)
```

*If* this fails, the API designer wanted you to make your own decision on how to deal with null values. That is a good decision, as implicit assumptions about null values tend to cause a lot of trouble and hard to find bugs.

Make your own decision, e.g.:

```
final Long x;
if (numberAsString == null)
  x = 0; // or null, although I'd see this as bad style.
else
  x = NumberUtil.createLong(numberAsString);
```

This example does not deal with the scenario of `numberAsString` containing any text not resembling an actual long value.